# Will it be infinite when call __getattribute__ in __getattr__?

Tags: python

In the official doc, `__getattr__` will be called when `__getattribute__` raise an AttributeError. 
But the code did not come into an infinite loop, why?

```
class A:
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return self.__getattribute__(item)

a = A()
print(a.d)
```

It just throw a AttributeError, how to explain it?

Comment: @hansolo yeah, I revoked my comment on further inspection of the problem

Comment: In Python 3, the documentation says something along the following: _If you access an attribute, first `__getattribute__` is called and if that fails `__getattr__` is called._ This does **not** mean that `__getattribute__` calls `__getattr__`.

Comment: Special methods are directly looked up in new style classes. Try this in `python2` without inheriting from `object` and you can see it recursing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This debugging `print` will help you to understand what is going on:

```
class A:
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        print('__getattr__ called for item {}'.format(item))
        return self.__getattribute__(item)

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        print('__getattribute__ called for item {}'.format(item))
        return object.__getattribute__(self, item)

a = A()
print(a.d)
```

Output:

```
__getattribute__ called for item d
__getattr__ called for item d
__getattribute__ called for item __getattribute__
__getattribute__ called for item d
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'd'
```

- `__getattribute__` is called first.
- After failure of `__getattribute__` lookup algorithm calls `__getattr__`.
- Inside it in `self.__getattribute__` also `__getattribute__` is called for item `__getattribute__`.
- Now `__getattribute__` is called for item d, but not in the flow of lookup algorithm because it was called directly, so `__getattr__` will not be called.
- `object.__getattribute__(self, item)` can't find `d` so error is raised.

Comment: yh, thank you for your answer,   lookup algorithm will be used only in default attribute access, that's why the code does not go into infinite, is it?

Comment: Yes, lookup algorithm is used only for `a.d`, not for `a.__getattribute__('d')` nor for `a.__getattr__('d')`